# Floating point representation of a real number is not unique

Tags: floating-point, language-agnostic, discrete-mathematics

I am reading about floating point representation of real numbers.
In any real number system with arithmetic base β, a real number x can be represented as
x=(0.d<sub>1</sub>d<sub>2</sub> --- d<sub>t</sub>d<sub>t+1</sub>---) <sub>β</sub> X β<sup>e</sup> **(1)**
where 0≤d<sub>i</sub>≤β-1
Now consider (0.5)<sub>10</sub> in binary system.
In binary system,
(0.5)<sub>{10}</sub>=(0.1)<sub>2</sub> **(2)**
But we can see that
1/2=(1/2<sup>2</sup>)+(1/2<sup>3</sup>)+----
(0.5)<sub>10</sub>=(0.01111---)<sub>2</sub> **(3)**

From **(2)** and **(3)** we can see that the same number has two floating point representation.

I have read that such ambiguities can be removed by considering the "normalized floating point representation" i.e.,
d<sub>1</sub> ≠ 0

But with the normalized floating point representation, we still have the ambiguity.
(0.5)<sub>10</sub>=(0.100000)<sub>2</sub>  **(2(a))**
(0.5)<sub>10</sub>=((0.1111111----) X 2<sup>-1</sup>)   **(3(a))**

So from **(2(a))** and **(3(a))** we can see that the ambiguity is not resolved still even with normalized floating point representation.
Can somebody please tell whether I am right. And how to resolve this ambiguity?

Comment: When actually storing a number you can only store a finite number of digits, which resolves the ambiguity (but of course also implies that you can't store every real number).

Comment: There is no “+----” in a floating-point format; there is no bit, or combination of bits or function of bits, in a normal floating-point encoding that indicates any part of it “goes on forever.” If there were, sure, maybe you could have two representations of the same number. In the formats commonly used for binary floating-point, there are no multiple representations of the same number (except there is a +0 and a −0). In some decimal formats, you may have multiple representations such as 3.1•10^1 and 31•10^0.

Comment: *We can see that the same number has two floating point representation.*  That's true in real mathematics, in a radix-notation representation of true real numbers.  Wikipedia has an article about it at [0.999999...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...).  But one of the key things to remember about computer floating point is that computer floating-point is *not* real mathematics, and it can *not* truly represent real numbers.  So results like your (2) and (3) basically have no meaning when it comes to computer floating point.

Comment: @SteveSummit it's not only floating point: there is only a countable infinity of real numbers that we can compute with an algorithm. So even if we would extend our number representations with algebraic numbers or some form of transcendentals, this would not include the vast majority of reals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... with the normalized floating point representation, we still have the ambiguity.

No ambiguity.

---

**(2(a))**  (0.5)<sub>10</sub> = (0.100000)<sub>2</sub>
**(3(a))I** (0.5)<sub>10</sub> = ((0.1111111----)<sub>2</sub> X 2<sup>-1</sup>  (as an infinite series)
**(3(a))F** (0.5)<sub>10</sub> = ((0.1111111----)<sub>2</sub> X 2<sup>-1</sup>  (as a finite series)

**(2(a))** is true.
**(3(a))I** is true.
**(3(a))F** is false as the number of terms in a floating point value is finite.  This is no more true than 1.0 equals 0.999999999999999.

**(3(a))I** is not possible with common binary floating point.  All finite values have only 1 encoding, except +0.0 and -0.0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a one basic question. We know that for a finite precision, there is rounding off of the numbers. So a computer can round off the second representation of the 0.5 thus storing it with some error. How a computer decide which representation to take? Is the error is the criterion of choosing the representation of a number because there will be no error in storing the first representation of 0.5.

Comment: (3(a)) (0.5)10 = ((0.1111111----)2 X 2-1 is true.  Real world floats are finite, so 0.1111111---- does not exist.

Comment: @Andrew Reworded to make clear **3(a)** truthfulness.

Comment: @Iti "We know that for a finite precision, there is rounding off of the numbers. " --> not always.  Code `0.5` can be exactly encoded in floating point.

Comment: @Iti "So a computer can round off the second representation of the 0.5 thus storing it with some error." is amiss as that 2nd representation with an infinite series is not possible in a computer with finite memory.  A compiler reads code and coverts to code the the exact floating point value when it can.  When it cannot, it is converted to the next higher or lower encodable floating pointer value.  The selection is usually the _closest_.

Comment: @Iti  "For decimal floating constants, ..., the result is either the nearest representable value, or the larger or smaller representable
value immediately adjacent to the nearest representable value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner".  C17 § 6.4.4.2 3.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, Thanks for the discussion. Now I have understood.